# Partial fraction decomposition of $\frac {2x^2 + x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

**Problem:** Expand $$\frac {2x^2 + x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$$ using partial fraction decomposition.

I wrote the following $$\frac A {x+1} + \frac B {x^2 + 1} = \frac {x(2x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2+1)} \\ A(x^2+1) + B(x+1) = x(2x + 1).$$  Plugging $x = 0$, I get $$A + B = 0.$$ Plugging in $x = 1$, I get $$2(A+B) = 3,$$ a contradiction.  Where is my mistake? And how should I solve this?

Also: I could separate the initial expression into $$\frac {2x^2}{(x+1)(x^2+1)} + \frac {x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$$ but am not sure if that would help (and, if it would, how should I know to do this?).

Comment: Don’t you need to do $\dfrac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in assuming that the rational function admits a decomposition of the form
$$\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{x^2+1}.$$
Instead, the decomposition would have the form
$$\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B \color{red}{x + C}}{x^2 + 1}$$ because the denominator of the second term has degree $2$.  If you now use this form, you will find
$$A(x^2 + 1) + (Bx + C)(x+1) = (A+B)x^2 + (B+C)x + (A+C) = 2x^2 + x$$
hence
we require
$$C = -A, \quad B = -C + 1, \quad A = -B + 2.$$
Substituting the first equation into the second, $B = A + 1$, and now substituting this into the third,
$$A = -(A+1) + 2 = -A + 1.$$
Therefore, $$A = \frac{1}{2}, \quad B = \frac{3}{2}, \quad C = -\frac{1}{2},$$
and
$$\frac{2x^2 + 2}{(x+1)(x^2+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{3x-1}{x^2+1}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

$B$ should be in general a linear polynomial. In the partial fraction decomposition the numerator is a polynomial of degree at most the degree in the denominator minus one.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ \frac{2 x^2+x}{(x+1)\left(x^2+1\right)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{f(x)}{x^2+1},
$$
then $$
2 x^2+x \equiv A\left(x^2+1\right)+(x+1) f(x)
$$
Putting $x=-1$ yields $1=2 A \Rightarrow A=\frac{1}{2}$.  Re-arranging gives
$$
f(x) =\frac{2 x^2+x-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+1\right)}{x+1}  =\frac{3 x-1}{2}
$$
Putting back yields
$$
\frac{2 x^2+x}{(x+1)\left(x^2+1\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{3 x-1}{x^2+1}\right)
$$